# Create unique list of dictionaries using dict keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries where I want to get a new list of dictionaries with unique two keys: 1. City, 2. Country.

```
list = [
 { City: "Gujranwala", Country: "Pakistan", other_columns },
 { City: "Gujrwanala", Country: "India", other_columns },
 { City: "Gujranwala", Country: "Pakistan", other_columns }
]
```

The output should be:

```
list = [
 { City: "Gujranwala", Country: "Pakistan", other_columns },
 { City: "Gujrwanala", Country: "India", other_columns }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many other and probably better approaches to this problem, but you can use:

```
l = [
 { "City": "Gujranwala", "Country": "Pakistan" },
 { "City": "Gujrwanala", "Country": "India" },
 { "City": "Gujranwala", "Country": "Pakistan" }
]

ll, v = [], set()

for d in l:
  k = d["City"] + d["Country"]
  if not k in v:
    v.add(k)
    ll.append(d)

print(ll)
# [{'City': 'Gujranwala', 'Country': 'Pakistan'}, {'City': 'Gujrwanala', 'Country': 'India'}]`
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/ee6c3a1e6e)

---

We basically create a list with unique values containing the city and country that we use to verify if both values are already present on the final list.

Comment: A quick way to improve this is to make `v` a set instead of a list, because that reduces `k in v` to O(1) instead of O(N)

Answer (score 2):

You can first extract the key-value pairs from the dicts and then remove duplicates by using a set. So you can do something like this:

1. Convert dicts into a list of dict_items:

```py
dict_items = [tuple(d.items()) for d in lst]  # they need to be tuples, otherwise you wouldn't be able to cast the list to a set
```

2. Deduplicate:

```py
deduplicated = set(dict_items)
```

3. Convert the dict_items back to dicts:

```py
back_to_dicts = [dict(i) for i in deduplicated]
```

Comment: You can improve this by making `dict_items` a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. By making it a generator expression and using lazy evaluation, you remove the need to do one loop `for d in lst` and another for `set(dict_items)`: `dict_items = (tuple(d.items()) for d in lst)`

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this reduction is to have a dictionary with a unique key for every `city`, `country` combination. In my case I've just concatenated both those properties for the key which is a simple working solution.

We are using a dictionary here as the lookup on a dictionary happens in constant time, so the whole algorithm will run in `O(n)`.

```py
lst = [
    {"City": "Gujranwala", "Country": "Pakistan"},
    {"City": "Gujrwanala", "Country": "India"},
    {"City": "Gujranwala", "Country": "Pakistan"}
]

unique = dict()
for item in lst:
    # concatenate key
    key = f"{item['City']}{item['Country']}"
    # only add the value to the dictionary if we do not already have an item with this key
    if not key in unique:
        unique[key] = item

# get the dictionary values (we don't care about the keys now)
result = list(unique.values())
print(result)
```

Expected ouput:

```
[{'City': 'Gujranwala', 'Country': 'Pakistan'}, {'City': 'Gujrwanala', 'Country': 'India'}]
```